# regex to detect two words in consecutive lines

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bunch of text files I need to remove some patterns using regexes in bash. JUST REGEX. An example:

```
brown blue
sad happy
orange green
sad happy
brown blue
orange green
```

Want to detect when "brown blue" is followed by newline and "sad happy" and then only in this case remove "brown blue" in the output. This is the expected outcome:

```
sad happy
orange green
sad happy
brown blue
orange green
```

What I've tried so far is not detecting the newline what is my needed first step to remove the desired line. Something like this:

```
(?<=blue).*(?=happy)

'blue\nhappy'
```

Comment: Are you using `grep`? Use `grep -Poz '(?<=blue).*(?=happy)'`

Comment: try `brown blue(?=\ssad happy)`

Comment: just the regex is needed

Comment: What are you using to perform the replacement, sed? If so, you may want to take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

Comment: the issue needs to be resolved only using regex

Comment: The logic might be a bit simpler if you reverse the lines in the file (with `tac`). Then, when you see "sad happy", check the **next** line for "brown blue". [tag:awk] or [tag:sed] will work here.

Comment: regex is neither a program nor a programming language, so you need a tool which is able to perform regexp matching and removing some text.

Comment: You could employ a buffer/variable without reversing in awk: `awk 'buffer~/brown\sblue/ && $0~/sad\shappy/{buffer=$0;next}buffer{print buffer}{buffer=$0}END{print buffer}'` I'm certain that can be refactored a bit, but it works fine.

Comment: Also... I have no idea what "Just regex in bash" is supposed to mean. What program are you applying that regex through?

Comment: My bad, reflex in bash means I have a bash machine to test the regex but the usual tools , sed, grep, awk and such will not be used in the target program.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the OP's requirement correctly, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

nl=$'\n'

str="brown blue
sad happy
orange green
sad happy
brown blue
orange green"

if [[ "$str" =~ ^(.*)brown\ blue${nl}(sad\ happy.*)$ ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

which yields:

```
sad happy
orange green
sad happy
brown blue
orange green
```

Although I'm still not sure what "just the regex" means.